# Is there a replacement of PropertySourcesBinder in Spring Boot 2.X.X?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

In Spring Boot 1.X.X there was a class named PropertySourcesBinder.class . Please check the API link.
[PropertySourcesBinder.class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.7.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/bind/PropertySourcesBinder.html)

The purpose of the class is simple - receiving a `org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment environment` in the constructor, it was easy to use the `extractAll (String somePrefixHere)` properties starting with the given prefix. However seems like in Spring Boot 2.X.X this class is missing.

This very method however was very useful since creating Map<String subKey, Map<String, Map>> with the properties recursively that match the prefix, same way omitting the prefix itself, which is very useful when having Spring "deep" properties like A.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I..... and you do not know how deep exactly it will go.

I am afraid my question is not very clear, however believe people have been using this class will understand what exactly my problem is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should use the new `Binder` API:

```java
ConfigurableEnvironment environment = new StandardEnvironment();
Map<String, Object> source = new HashMap<>();
source.put("your.prefix.a.b.c.e.f", "one");
source.put("your.prefix.a.b.c.e.g", "two");
source.put("your.prefix.a.b.c.e.h.i.j.k", "three");
environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource("example", source));

Bindable<Map<String, Map>> bindable = Bindable.mapOf(String.class, Map.class);
Map<String, Map> bound = Binder.get(environment).bind("your.prefix", bindable).get();
System.out.println(bound);
```

The above will output the following:

```
{a={b={c={e={f=one, g=two, h={i={j={k=three}}}}}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy Wilkinson this is exactly what I needed. What Cozimetzer proposed is also valid, however I need exactly something to map to a Map recursively. Very nice. Thanks for fast response Andy .

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = “myprops”)
```

Here is an example:

[Baeldung example for ConfigurationProperties](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)